# static and dynamic polymorphism in c#

Tags: c#

I know Polymorphism can be static or dynamic.

1. static Polymorphism

   - Function overloading
   - Operator overloading
2. Dynamic Polymorphism

[image]

But my question is I am unable to find this two type in msdn documentation
 [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173152.aspx)

why they are not describing this two type(static and dynamic Polymorphism)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The view expressed in your question, that polymorphism is either static or dynamic, is just a single point of view. Another point of view is that polymorphism means what you refer to as dynamic polymorphism.

That other point of view is also perfectly valid. And it appears that is the point of view taken by the authors of the MSDN topic to which you refer.

For what it is worth, some authors refer to another type of polymorphism, namely parametric polymorphism, to describe generic programming. These are all just different points of view. However, dynamic polymorphism has primacy in object-oriented programming and it is very common for authors to regard polymorphism as referring to dynamic polymorphism, a.k.a. subtype polymorphism.

Comment: +1 I don't really consider compile-time polymorphism to be really polymorphism.

Comment: @Euphoric I don't want to make any judgement. If some people think of static overload resolution as polymorphism, that's fine by me.